# Is it possible to map a map<String,List<Entity>> in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm thinking if i use maps like `Map<String,List<Entity>>` or `Map<Long,List<Entity>>` it will help me with a few things, but I couldn't find any example to map that kind of map.

My question is, is it possible to do that kind of mapping in JPA standards, and what kind of annotation I should use?

Comment: See, http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is apparently no, as per [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices) in the comment to original post and I can also confirm that it does not work in Eclipselink from what I tried.

I tried to do a nested Map<String, List<>> where key would be an ISO2 language code which would help retreiving only a specific subset of child relations which satisfy the current language context.

Something like this:

```
public class ProductEntity {

  @MapKey(name = "language")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,   fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Map<String, List<AttributeEntity>> attributes;

}

public class AttributeEntity {

  private String language;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
  private ProductEntity product;
}
```

This would be useful when you need to retreive attributes for a specific language (coming from REST Accept-Language header for example) since you could just `getAttributes().get(currentLanguage)` instead of writing NamedQueries or do stream filtering.

At least for Eclipselink, I got a nonsensical error when I attempted this:

> IllegalArgumentException: Object:
> [com.my.project.AttributeEntity@745f] is not a known Entity type.

Perhaps Hibernate has some tricks to support this but I didn't test it. My guess would be - no.