# I am wanting to use a List<String> as a value of the map. I want to persist this class in JPA. Not able to put data in such an entity class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

I am wanting to use a `List<String>` as a value of the map. I want to persist this class in JPA. Is there any way possible.

The code seems simple

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

How should i make the setter method for this map element .

There seems to be an error when i'm trying to persist data in the entity.

It is not able to read data from the `List<String>` into the map value.

Comment: I don't understand this kind of thinking combined with JPA.  ORM means mapping an object model that represents your domain to a relational schema, not Java collection classes.  I'd use straight SQL, Spring JDBC template, iBatis, or something else in this case.  Or just ditch JPA.  What's it buying you here?  Nothing but confusion and grief.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to map a map<String,List<Entity>> in JPA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784101/is-it-possible-to-map-a-mapstring-listentity-in-jpa)

Comment: I understand but have to implement this class using JPA, cannot dump the technology. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Problem happening here is the third level of table. First level is the entity class itself. That is getting properly made. The second level for the hash map is getting properly made. But the third level i.e. the List<String> for the value of the map is causing a problem. There is no problem if both key and value is string for the map.

Comment: No the difference is the List is of String type and does not store another enity.

Comment: I have tried doing this but it is unable to read the list into the list, anyways lemme go thru the link and try it out. Thanks